# Const object TypeScript

Tags: typescript, react-native

I'm trying to use the property of an object that is located under the "common" folder inside one of my files that is located under my mobile directory.

there is no compile time error.

When I remove the `as const` it works. but then my object clearly doesn't have read-only properties.

I get the following error.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: If you remove `as const` and it works, it's an indication that the file is not being transpiled properly, as it is a pure typescript construct.

Comment: [Please replace/supplement images of code/errors with plaintext versions.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/2887218).  And is it possible for you to provide a [mre] suitable for demonstrating your issue in a standalone IDE (or give a link to a web IDE project that demonstrates the issue)?  If not then it's hard to diagnose what's going on.

Comment: @Terry sounds like the issue, so what is the solution, I'm using the same object from the common directory in my server(Node) and it works fine.

Comment: How are you transpiling your file? Are you using babel or the likes?

Comment: I do use babel.

`module.exports = function(api) {
  api.cache(true);
  return {
    presets: ['babel-preset-expo'],
  };
};
`

Answer (score 0):

You can use Object.freeze to declare an object as read only.

```
export const API = Object.freeze({login:"/login"});
API.login = "another url";
console.log(API.login) // It prints /login
```

Comment: TypeScript doesn’t recognize this as a true constant — Object.freeze() makes use of some somewhat crazy runtime checks that throw an error if you try to modify it